# How would I make it so that a border only spans a certain length, on one side?

Tags: html, css

How would I make it so that a border only spans a certain length, on one side? I tried

```
<ul id = 'list'>
    <li class = 'list-item'>example1</li>
    <li class = 'list-item'>example2</li>
    <li class = 'list-item'>example3</li>
</ul>
```

and the css:

```
<style>
#list{
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline;
}
.list-item{
 float:left;
 border-left:solid 5px red;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: What do you mean with certain length?

Comment: I mean like only spanning half of the border

Comment: You don't easily. You'd have to create a pseudoelement absolutely positioned, using half the height.

Comment: more like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yojOwO ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `line-height` hack:

```css
#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

.list-item {
  float: left;
  border-left: solid 5px red;
  line-height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>example1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>example2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>example3</li>
</ul>
```

The pseudo-element hack:

```css
#list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

.list-item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.list-item:after {
  content: '';
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50%;
  left: -5px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id='list'>
  <li class='list-item'>example1</li>
  <li class='list-item'>example2</li>
  <li class='list-item'>example3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work if the text spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to have a border take up **part** of the width or height of an element is to make use of **two** elements - a parent and child (or an element that is absolutely-positioned).

Vertical borders should be specified on the element with the smaller `height`, and horizontal borders should be specified on the element with the smaller `width`.

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 5px solid red;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  border-left: solid 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer et ex sed mi luctus luctus sed sed mauris. Cras pretium nisi non odio rhoncus, id viverra erat rutrum. Vivamus congue ultrices sem maximus tempor. Suspendisse in est gravida, elementum lorem eget, tincidunt urna.</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)